# How to authenticate google cloud functions for access to secure app engine endpoints

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-authentication

Google Cloud Platform has introduced Identity Aware Proxy for protecting App Engine Flexible environment instances from public access.

However, it is not entirely clear if this can or should be used from Google Cloud Functions that are accessing GAE hosted API endpoints.

The [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/iap/docs/authentication-howto) (with Python and Java examples) indicates an IAP authentication workflow consisting of 1) generating a JWT token, 2) creating an OpenID Token, 3) Then submitting requests to Google App Engine with an `Authorization: Bearer TOKEN` header.

This seems quite convoluted for running cloud functions if authorisation has to happen each time a function is called.

Is there another way for Google cloud functions to access secured GAE endpoints?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you want to make calls from GCF to IAP protected app, you should indeed be using ID tokens. There are no examples in Nodejs so I made one using [this](https://github.com/extrabacon/google-oauth-jwt/blob/master/lib/auth.js) as a reference (style may be wrong since that's the first time I touch nodejs). Unlike regular JWT claims set, it should not contain scope and have target_audience.

```
/**
 * Make IAP request
 *
 */
exports.CfToIAP = function CfToIAP (req, res) {
  var crypto = require('crypto'),
      request = require('request');
  var token_URL = "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v4/token";
  // service account private key (copied from service_account.json)
  var key = "-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----\nMIIEvQexsQ1DBNe12345GRwAZM=\n-----END PRIVATE KEY-----\n";

  // craft JWT
  var JWT_header = new Buffer(JSON.stringify({ alg: "RS256", typ: "JWT" })).toString('base64');
  // prepare claims set
  var iss = "12345@12345.iam.gserviceaccount.com";  // service account email address (copied from service_account.json)
  var aud = "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v4/token";
  var iat = Math.floor(new Date().getTime() / 1000);
  var exp = iat + 120; // no need for a long linved token since it's not cached
  var target_audience = "12345.apps.googleusercontent.com"; // this is the IAP client ID that can be obtained by clicking 3 dots -> Edit OAuth Client in IAP configuration page
  var claims = {
    iss: iss,
    aud: aud,
    iat: iat,
    exp: exp,
    target_audience: target_audience
  };
  var JWT_claimset = new Buffer(JSON.stringify(claims)).toString('base64');
  // concatenate header and claimset
  var unsignedJWT = [JWT_header, JWT_claimset].join('.');
  // sign JWT
  var JWT_signature = crypto.createSign('RSA-SHA256').update(unsignedJWT).sign(key, 'base64');
  var signedJWT = [unsignedJWT, JWT_signature].join('.');
  // get id_token and make IAP request
  request.post({url:token_URL, form: {grant_type:'urn:ietf:params:oauth:grant-type:jwt-bearer', assertion:signedJWT}}, function(err,res,body){
    var data = JSON.parse(body);
    var bearer = ['Bearer', data.id_token].join(' ');
    var options = {
      url: 'https://1234.appspot.com/', // IAP protected GAE app
      headers: {
        'User-Agent': 'cf2IAP',
        'Authorization': bearer
      }
    };
    request(options, function (err, res, body) {
      console.log('error:', err);
    });
  });
  res.send('done');
};

/**
 * package.json
 *
 */

{
  "name": "IAP-test",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "dependencies": {
    "request": ">=2.83"
  }
}
```

**Update: Bundling service account key is not recommended, so a better option is to use the metadata server. For the below sample to work Google Identity and Access Management (IAM) API should be enabled and App Engine default service account should have Service Account Actor role (default Editor is not enough):**

```
/**
 * Make request from CF to a GAE app behind IAP:
 * 1) get access token from the metadata server.
 * 2) prepare JWT and use IAM APIs projects.serviceAccounts.signBlob method to avoid bundling service account key.
 * 3) 'exchange' JWT for ID token.
 * 4) make request with ID token.
 *
 */
exports.CfToIAP = function CfToIAP (req, res) {
  // imports and constants
  const request = require('request');
  const user_agent = '<user_agent_to_identify_your_CF_call>';
  const token_URL = "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v4/token";
  const project_id = '<project_ID_where_CF_is_deployed>';
  const service_account = [project_id,
                           '@appspot.gserviceaccount.com'].join(''); // app default service account for CF project
  const target_audience = '<IAP_client_ID>';
  const IAP_GAE_app = '<IAP_protected_GAE_app_URL>';

  // prepare request options and make metadata server access token request
  var meta_req_opts = {
    url: ['http://metadata.google.internal/computeMetadata/v1/instance/service-accounts/',
          service_account,
          '/token'].join(''),
    headers: {
      'User-Agent': user_agent,
      'Metadata-Flavor': 'Google'
    }
  };
  request(meta_req_opts, function (err, res, body) {
    // get access token from response
    var meta_resp_data = JSON.parse(body);
    var access_token = meta_resp_data.access_token;

    // prepare JWT that is {Base64url encoded header}.{Base64url encoded claim set}.{Base64url encoded signature}
    // https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2ServiceAccount for more info
    var JWT_header = new Buffer(JSON.stringify({ alg: "RS256", typ: "JWT" })).toString('base64');
    var iat = Math.floor(new Date().getTime() / 1000);
    // prepare claims set and base64 encode it
    var claims = {
      iss: service_account,
      aud: token_URL,
      iat: iat,
      exp: iat + 60, // no need for a long lived token since it's not cached
      target_audience: target_audience
    };
    var JWT_claimset = new Buffer(JSON.stringify(claims)).toString('base64');

    // concatenate JWT header and claims set and get signature usign IAM APIs projects.serviceAccounts.signBlob method
    var to_sign = [JWT_header, JWT_claimset].join('.');    
    // sign JWT using IAM APIs projects.serviceAccounts.signBlob method
    var signature_req_opts = {
      url: ['https://iam.googleapis.com/v1/projects/',
            project_id,
            '/serviceAccounts/',
            service_account,
            ':signBlob'].join(''),
      method: "POST",
      json: {
        "bytesToSign": new Buffer(to_sign).toString('base64')
      },
      headers: {
        'User-Agent': user_agent,
        'Authorization': ['Bearer', access_token].join(' ')
      }
    };
    request(signature_req_opts, function (err, res, body) {
      // get signature from response and form JWT
      var JWT_signature = body.signature;
      var JWT = [JWT_header, JWT_claimset, JWT_signature].join('.');

      // obtain ID token
      request.post({url:token_URL, form: {grant_type:'urn:ietf:params:oauth:grant-type:jwt-bearer', assertion:JWT}}, function(err, res, body){
        // use ID token to make a request to the IAP protected GAE app
        var ID_token_resp_data = JSON.parse(body);
        var ID_token = ID_token_resp_data.id_token;
        var IAP_req_opts = {
          url: IAP_GAE_app,
          headers: {
            'User-Agent': user_agent,
            'Authorization': ['Bearer', ID_token].join(' ')
          }
        };
        request(IAP_req_opts, function (err, res, body) {
          console.log('error:', err);
        });
      });
    });
  });
  res.send('done');
};
```

Comment: Do you know if there is likely to be a performance overhead for authenticating each cloud function request?

Comment: As additional protection layer it would have small end-to-end latency impact, but authentication is not happening on the instance level, so there shouldn't be CPU time impact.

Comment: Actually that's not a good approach since it requires bundling private key which is not recommended. Better approach is to use metadata server. I'll update the sample later.

Comment: Simpler answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62803317/620699

Comment: See GCP official answer: https://cloud.google.com/iap/docs/authentication-howto#iap_make_request-nodejs

Answer (score 7):

For anyone still looking at this 2020 and beyond Google has made this very easy.

Their [docs](https://cloud.google.com/iap/docs/authentication-howto#iap_make_request-nodejs) have an example of how to auth IAP that works great in Cloud Functions:

```js
// const url = 'https://some.iap.url';
// const targetAudience = 'IAP_CLIENT_ID.apps.googleusercontent.com';

const {GoogleAuth} = require('google-auth-library');
const auth = new GoogleAuth();

async function request() {
  console.info(`request IAP ${url} with target audience ${targetAudience}`);
  const client = await auth.getIdTokenClient(targetAudience);
  const res = await client.request({url});
  console.info(res.data);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

python example:

```
from google.auth.transport.requests import Request as google_request
from google.oauth2 import id_token

open_id_connect_token = id_token.fetch_id_token(google_request(), client_id)
```

where client_id is string. Navigate to APIs & Services part of GCP, then select credentails on the left, there is client_id in OAuth2.0 part in AIP

[image]

when yoy want to make request to secured IAP service, just add to headers

```
{'Authorization': 'Bearer your_open_id_connect_token'}
```

source: https://cloud.google.com/iap/docs/authentication-howto

Answer (score 0):

As discussed in this [doc](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/), you can authenticate to a Google Cloud Platform (GCP) API using:

1- Service Accounts (preferred method) - use of a Google account that is associated with your GCP project, as opposed to a specific user.

2- User Accounts - used when app needs to access resources on behalf of an end user.

3- API keys - generally used when calling APIs that don’t need to access private data.

Comment: the GAE sits behind the Identity Aware Protection which appears to require following the docs referenced in the original post. I'm under the impression (and wasn't succesful in my efforts) that setting `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` isn't enough for IAP?

Comment: Setting the Application Default Credentials should be enough. You can read more about it on this [thread](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/application-default-credentials). Please feel free to post the logs if you have trouble integrating it.

Comment: is there a way to set environment variables for cloud functions? Not sure how one would set `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` otherwise?

Comment: This answer is not correct for the IAP question raised here.

Answer (score 0):

some people use the Google CLOUD KEY MANAGEMENT SERVICE (KMS) to avoid hardcoding them in the cloud function.

https://cloud.google.com/kms/