# Allow cloud functions ip from app engine firewall rules

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-functions

We have created an app engine instance to work as backend and another one is from cloud function.
Now cloud functions needs to access the api from app engine within the same google project this works fine if the firewall from app engine allows everyone to access. But in our case we need to restrict the access from cloud function only.

I'm new to GCP I would higly appreciate your suggestions. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

The best solution would be to activate the [IAP for App Engine](https://cloud.google.com/iap/docs) ( Identity aware proxy ). [Here](https://cloud.google.com/iap/docs/app-engine-quickstart#enabling_iap) you can find a guide on how to activate your IAP on App Engine.

IAP will interdict the acces of anyone, any application to access your App Engine instance, but the one you will allow manually. In your situation you will need to allow the Cloud Functions service account to access your application. You can check on [this guide](https://cloud.google.com/iap/docs/authentication-howto) on how to achieve that programmatically from Cloud Functions. You have examples for C#, Python, Java and PHP.

eg Python :

```
import google.auth
import google.auth.app_engine
import google.auth.compute_engine.credentials
import google.auth.iam
from google.auth.transport.requests import Request
import google.oauth2.credentials
import google.oauth2.service_account
import requests
import requests_toolbelt.adapters.appengine


IAM_SCOPE = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/iam'
OAUTH_TOKEN_URI = 'https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v4/token'


def make_iap_request(url, client_id, method='GET', **kwargs):
    """Makes a request to an application protected by Identity-Aware Proxy.
Args:
  url: The Identity-Aware Proxy-protected URL to fetch.
  client_id: The client ID used by Identity-Aware Proxy.
  method: The request method to use
          ('GET', 'OPTIONS', 'HEAD', 'POST', 'PUT', 'PATCH', 'DELETE')
  **kwargs: Any of the parameters defined for the request function:
            https://github.com/requests/requests/blob/master/requests/api.py
            If no timeout is provided, it is set to 90 by default.

Returns:
  The page body, or raises an exception if the page couldn't be retrieved.
"""
# Set the default timeout, if missing
if 'timeout' not in kwargs:
    kwargs['timeout'] = 90

# Figure out what environment we're running in and get some preliminary
# information about the service account.
bootstrap_credentials, _ = google.auth.default(
    scopes=[IAM_SCOPE])
if isinstance(bootstrap_credentials,
              google.oauth2.credentials.Credentials):
    raise Exception('make_iap_request is only supported for service '
                    'accounts.')
elif isinstance(bootstrap_credentials,
                google.auth.app_engine.Credentials):
    requests_toolbelt.adapters.appengine.monkeypatch()

# For service account's using the Compute Engine metadata service,
# service_account_email isn't available until refresh is called.
bootstrap_credentials.refresh(Request())

signer_email = bootstrap_credentials.service_account_email
if isinstance(bootstrap_credentials,
              google.auth.compute_engine.credentials.Credentials):
    # Since the Compute Engine metadata service doesn't expose the service
    # account key, we use the IAM signBlob API to sign instead.
    # In order for this to work:
    #
    # 1. Your VM needs the https://www.googleapis.com/auth/iam scope.
    #    You can specify this specific scope when creating a VM
    #    through the API or gcloud. When using Cloud Console,
    #    you'll need to specify the "full access to all Cloud APIs"
    #    scope. A VM's scopes can only be specified at creation time.
    #
    # 2. The VM's default service account needs the "Service Account Actor"
    #    role. This can be found under the "Project" category in Cloud
    #    Console, or roles/iam.serviceAccountActor in gcloud.
    signer = google.auth.iam.Signer(
        Request(), bootstrap_credentials, signer_email)
else:
    # A Signer object can sign a JWT using the service account's key.
    signer = bootstrap_credentials.signer

# Construct OAuth 2.0 service account credentials using the signer
# and email acquired from the bootstrap credentials.
service_account_credentials = google.oauth2.service_account.Credentials(
    signer, signer_email, token_uri=OAUTH_TOKEN_URI, additional_claims={
        'target_audience': client_id
    })

# service_account_credentials gives us a JWT signed by the service
# account. Next, we use that to obtain an OpenID Connect token,
# which is a JWT signed by Google.
google_open_id_connect_token = get_google_open_id_connect_token(
    service_account_credentials)

# Fetch the Identity-Aware Proxy-protected URL, including an
# Authorization header containing "Bearer " followed by a
# Google-issued OpenID Connect token for the service account.
resp = requests.request(
    method, url,
    headers={'Authorization': 'Bearer {}'.format(
        google_open_id_connect_token)}, **kwargs)
if resp.status_code == 403:
    raise Exception('Service account {} does not have permission to '
                    'access the IAP-protected application.'.format(
                        signer_email))
elif resp.status_code != 200:
    raise Exception(
        'Bad response from application: {!r} / {!r} / {!r}'.format(
            resp.status_code, resp.headers, resp.text))
else:
    return resp.text


def get_google_open_id_connect_token(service_account_credentials):
    """Get an OpenID Connect token issued by Google for the service account.

This function:

  1. Generates a JWT signed with the service account's private key
     containing a special "target_audience" claim.

  2. Sends it to the OAUTH_TOKEN_URI endpoint. Because the JWT in #1
     has a target_audience claim, that endpoint will respond with
     an OpenID Connect token for the service account -- in other words,
     a JWT signed by *Google*. The aud claim in this JWT will be
     set to the value from the target_audience claim in #1.

For more information, see
https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2ServiceAccount .
The HTTP/REST example on that page describes the JWT structure and
demonstrates how to call the token endpoint. (The example on that page
shows how to get an OAuth2 access token; this code is using a
modified version of it to get an OpenID Connect token.)
"""

service_account_jwt = (
    service_account_credentials._make_authorization_grant_assertion())
request = google.auth.transport.requests.Request()
body = {
    'assertion': service_account_jwt,
    'grant_type': google.oauth2._client._JWT_GRANT_TYPE,
}
token_response = google.oauth2._client._token_endpoint_request(
    request, OAUTH_TOKEN_URI, body)
return token_response['id_token']
```

In case you use a Cloud Function on Nodejs, a StackOverflow user created an example on how to achieve the same for Nodejs in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45787676/how-to-authenticate-google-cloud-functions-for-access-to-secure-app-engine-endpo).

Comment: I often read that the solution is IAP, in my use case I have both an active IAP and firewall. IAP alone may work for people but it's not a direct answer to the question, which is, how to pierce the firewall with the cloud function? Wish I knew!